# SQLITE- Empty string returns value of 0 ( Integer field)

Tags: sqlite

I wanted to query all records that have a value of 0 . This is the query.

```
SELECT * FROM TN_REVISION WHERE TN_TABLENAME='TEST_ABC'
```

When I visually looked it via SQLite Expert Personal, I get this
[Results from the above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogw1K.jpg)

However, the last row is actually having an empty string ( although I see a 0 value). When I use `SELECT * FROM TN_REVISION WHERE TN_TABLENAME='TEST_ABC' and revision_num=0`, I see only 1 row instead of 2.
Note: Revision_num is of INTEGER data type. Can someone please tell me why this is the case?

Comment: Can you share the table schema?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [TN_REVISION] (
  [TN_TABLENAME] VARCHAR(40) COLLATE NOCASE, 
  [TN_USERNAME] VARCHAR(20), 
  [LAST_REVISION_DT] DATETIME, 
  [REVISION_NUM] INTEGER)

Comment: Can't reproduce. Might help if you could provide an actual dump of at least those rows of the table.